# HTTP 404 Server Error in '/' Application. in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

`First, this is my first MVC code & I tried to search for the solution to the problem in this site & I checked all the possible cases like routeconfig file, controller,action properties & I tried to put appropriate values in specified page of Web Tab of Project Property. But still it showing the same error. Some help please.

[image]

here my routeconfig file

```
namespace Deepak_MVC_2
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "GetStudents", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

specific page entry :  Student/GetStudents

```
namespace Deepak_MVC_2.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetAllStudent()
        {
            StudentModelManager smm = new StudentModelManager();
            List<StudentModel> lsm = smm.GetAllStudentInfo();
            ActionResult ar = View("GetStudents",lsm);
            return ar;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you ad your controller code please?

Comment: Do you have a `GetStudents` action method in `StudentController` ?

Comment: No, the action method is GetAllStudent(). You can see now since I have updated it. The view name is GetStudents.cshtml.

Answer (score 1):

Update your controller's action to match the View you want. with that You can actually remove the name when returning the view as convention will match the `ViewName` to the action name.

```
namespace Deepak_MVC_2.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetStudents()
        {
            StudentModelManager smm = new StudentModelManager();
            List<StudentModel> lsm = smm.GetAllStudentInfo();
            ActionResult ar = View(lsm);
            return ar;
        }
    }
}
```

this will allow

```
GET /Student/GetStudents
```

to be matched to the correct view as in your image